# Turning an HTML template into a Django template

Tags: html, django

When you purchase an HTML template, usually everything is mixed in together... html, css, images and js.

An example template may look like this:

account.html
category.html
contact.html
/fonts
/img
item-detail.html
media.html
register.html
style.css
author.html
category-tile.html
/css
/images
index.html
/js
new.html
shortcodes.html
submit.php

Django has static files and templates in separate folders in most cases. Is there a proper way of going about this?

Answer (score 1):

I would start by moving all the /fonts, /css, and other static files to my static dir.

Then I'd look at the various html files, try to figure out what common elements are shared, and extract those common elements to a base template that can be imported by the various children ([this page](https://oncampus.oberlin.edu/webteam/2012/09/architecture-django-templates) gives a nice starting point for approaching template style & inheritance). Hopefully by starting with the base template, I could change the paths to static assets in that file alone, and avoid having to change them in each individual child template, but there's always `sed`, vim macros, or similar tools.

Then I'd go through all the html files and convert each of them to child templates extending the base template. Presumably this would involve some looping between "edit the base" and "edit the children," possibly with some intermediate or unrelated "base" templates if the theme is complicated enough.